# How to interpret the ddosify engine report?

Tags: performance-testing, load-testing

I was reading the documentation for ddosify engine and it's not quite clear to me if the number of iterations runs parallelly, or if that is parametrized with the property engine_mode?

Aditionally, I'm not sure what the number that appears after "'Succesful Run'" refers to, such as below. I thought it was the number of iterations but I noticed it is not constant across rows when running a lineal charge.

```
~ # ddosify -t https://target.com/ -l linear
⚙️  Initializing...
 Engine fired.

 CTRL+C to gracefully stop.
✔️  Successful Run: 12     100%       ❌ Failed Run: 0        0%       ⏱️  Avg. Duration: 0.20927s
✔️  Successful Run: 28     100%       ❌ Failed Run: 0        0%       ⏱️  Avg. Duration: 0.16199s
✔️  Successful Run: 43     100%       ❌ Failed Run: 0        0%       ⏱️  Avg. Duration: 0.14910s
✔️  Successful Run: 58     100%       ❌ Failed Run: 0        0%       ⏱️  Avg. Duration: 0.14227s
✔️  Successful Run: 73     100%       ❌ Failed Run: 0        0%       ⏱️  Avg. Duration: 0.13841s
✔️  Successful Run: 88     100%       ❌ Failed Run: 0        0%       ⏱️  Avg. Duration: 0.13620s
✔️  Successful Run: 100    100%       ❌ Failed Run: 0        0%       ⏱️  Avg. Duration: 0.13477s


RESULT
-------------------------------------
Success Count:    100   (100%)
Failed Count:     0     (0%)

Durations (Avg):
  DNS                  :0.0010s
  Connection           :0.0001s
  TLS                  :0.0085s
  Request Write        :0.0001s
  Server Processing    :0.1250s
  Response Read        :0.0001s
  Total                :0.1348s

Status Code (Message) :Count
  200 (OK)    :100

Test Status : Success
```

I tried looking in the documentation for the ddosify engine in github and on the official site of ddosify.

Answer (score 1):

An iteration represents a sequential user flow that you create with steps. Let's say you have three steps in the iteration. The second step starts running once the first step's response is received, a timeout occurs, or an error is encountered. You can configure the Ddosify Engine to run iterations in parallel, but the steps within an iteration will always run sequentially. The engine modes are designed to change the iteration creation strategy, which is unrelated to the execution of steps.

Unless an [assertion](https://github.com/ddosify/ddosify/tree/master/engine_docs#assertion) is created, if all the requests in a single iteration receive responses, Ddosify marks the iteration as a successful run. Otherwise, it is marked as a failed run. You can alter this default behavior by creating custom logic based on the response time, headers, etc., by leveraging the assertion logic.